# Rigify rig rotation problems

Tags: rigging

I rigged my character using the Rigify add on , but when I try to rotate the character's hands, the elbows rotate with it and it looks horrible, Does anyone know how to fix this? I'll attach a pic.[image]

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the vertex groups for the hand that's causing Blender to think some parts of the elbow are actually parts of the hand.  In that case, you would need to use weight painting to remove those vertices from the vertex group for the hand.

Comment: For some reason, I've seen a lot of people getting problems with bendy-bone arms in Rigify armatures, and that could explain your picture.  But I'd need to see a file to say for sure.

Comment: Looks like an error in the placement of Metarig bones: the hand bone has its head  on the elbow while it should be centered on the wrist.

Comment: Hey Everyone, I Tried Deleting And Regenerating The Rig And It Worked , Thanks For Your Help